# Merge code from one TFS server to a 2nd TFS sever that contains an old version of my code

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs

Hi I need to move my source code from one my existing TFS server to a new TFS server that is a clone of my existing one. From what I remember I think both servers are 2012 and I am using Visual Studio 2013 for development.

The clone already has my project on it, but it is an old version of the code. The existing server has the latest code but will be decommissioned soon.

Without having admin access on either server how can I move my code from the existing server with the latest code to the new server with an old version of the code.

Is it possible to do this and maintain the project history including the last month of development, or will I only be able to keep the code ? TFS is a managed service for me and I don't have the option to stay on the existing server.

I have only seen solutions where the new TFS server is clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Team Foundation Server Integration Tool: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe

With this tool, you're able to migrate source code with history.